# MVC4 Dynamic base64String looks fine in View.cshtml but browser appends extra characters and image is then not viewable

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a weird situation happening that seems like it should be pretty straight forward.

In my ViewModel, I have a list of base64strings that I iterate and load into a html image. After the browser has fully loaded, all I see is a blank [x].

However, if I place a break point in the controller, then copy and paste the base64 string directly into the img tag, the browser draws this out fine. What am i missing?

here is a sample of my html/razor code

```
foreach (var m in Model.ProfileList)
{
    var imgMime = "data:image/png;base64";
    var imgFullName = String.Format(imgMime,{0}", ProfileList.FullNameAsBase64String);

    <img id="@m.ID"
    src="@imgFullName"
    style="width:180px; height:30px"/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just about kicked myself on this one. On running the base64 string through textpad, realized i had unicode characters in the string. Cleaning those out in the controller before sending the base64 to the view fixed the issue.